# How to create a seek bar with Slider

Tags: sound, slider

I am trying to create a simple audio player but I am stuck at designing the seek bar. I am using the `AudioStream` framework.

After loading music in a variable `stream`, I can access its position using `stream["Position"]`. However, this returns the current position of the track as a Quantity instead of a Real number.

So when I put this in a slider, I cannot control the position of the audio

```
Slider[
    Dynamic[QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[stream["Position"], "Seconds"]],
    {0, stream["Duration"]}
 ]
```

This results in the error

```
Set::write: Tag QuantityMagnitude in QuantityMagnitude[0.s] is Protected.
```

Can anyone suggest a workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this will get you started?

```
stream = AudioStream[ExampleData[{"Audio", "ChurchBell"}]]
{Slider[
   Dynamic[
     QuantityMagnitude@stream["Position"], 
     (stream["Position"] = Quantity[#, "Seconds"]) &
   ], 
   {0., stream["Duration"]}
 ], 
 Dynamic[stream["Position"]]}
AudioPlay[stream]
```

The problem with your code is that by default `Dynamic` tries to assign the current value to whatever the first argument is. So it sees something like `QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[stream["Position"], "Seconds"] = somenewvalue` and it's saying that you cannot use `Set` on `QuantityMagnitude`.

My solution avoids this by making use of the second argument of `Dynamic`. So the value that is actually being tracked by the slider is `QuantityMagnitude@stream["Position"]`, basically the same as what you had. You can add your `UnitConvert` back in if you need it, but I didn't need it since my sample audio was short. But we don't want `Dynamic` to actually try to assign to that value. Instead, using the second argument, I tell it to convert the current raw value to seconds, and then assign that value to `stream["Position"]`.

You can see that as the audio plays, the position of the slider as well as the number afterwards changes.

I did notice that if you grab the slider while the audio is playing, it doesn't seem to want to play again. You could probably remedy this by having pause and play buttons using `stream["Status"] = "Paused"`, or making the `Dynamic` pause the audio whenever you click the slider.